# JVM: signing a PDF file in three steps

Tags: java, pdf, rsa, pdfbox, digital-signature

I have a website that allow users to sign any given uploaded file. The workflow is:

1. The user uploads a file. A SHA256 digest of the file is computed and stored in a database.
2. Other users signs the SHA256 digest using RSA. The signatures are added to the database.
3. Users can download files and signatures (currently in separate files). The signature files are generated upon request. The signature files are basically HTML files containing the checksum, signatures and certificates in Base64 and QRCode formats that can be printed for archiving.

Additionaly, the database also contains users' public keys and certificates (as well as encrypted private keys for non-technical users so that the app can handle the whole signing signature process for them).

Now I want to adapt the workflow for specific support of PDF files, as PDF files have specific support for signing. I have been struggling for a few days with PDFBox and have succeeded in signing a PDF file separately but I do not know how to adapt to my usual workflow.

The usage of signature for PDFBox is currently:

```
ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning =
                document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(output);

byte[] cmsSignature = sign(externalSigning.getContent());

externalSigning.setSignature(cmsSignature);
```

The signed PDF file is then streamed to `output`.

The computation of the digest and the signature, as well as incorporating the signature and certificates to the PDF file is made in one step in the "sign" method above, which means that I do not know how to implement my usual workflow of computing the digest (1), signing (2) and generating the signature file (3) in three steps. Moreover, I suppose that the `InputStream` given by `externalSigning.getContent()` does not contain the whole PDF file, which means that the digest and signature cannot be checked using my existing code?

Comment: You don't have to use PDF signing just because it's there. You can just use your own system and treat a pdf file like any other. Or, you can use both if you want to retain some of the benefits of PDF signing.

Comment: If you want to create integrated pdf signatures using pdfbox in multiple steps, you can let yourself be inspired by how eSignature DSS does that. They also insist on a multiple-steps signing and don't even want to keep a prepared pdf as temporary data, so they produce it twice identically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you will have to store PDF after adding signature field since pdf hash also include signature field properties. If you are trying to add signature field again at step 3 to the original pdf, the stored signature is not the one which matches new hash. You need to check if and how PDFBox allows this!

Comment: Well, he doesn't *have to* store it, it is also possible to *regenerate it identically* (a problem with this related to random numbers used in case of AES encryption is currently being resolved). Nonetheless, storing it temporarily also in my opinion is the better, cleaner option.

Comment: what I meant here is Signature field also has /M field with time, thus, it might not be possible to have same time and thus same hash to match with the hash we got at the time of calculating signature!

Comment: Well, additional issue is that several users can sign the original document, and I want to generate in fine a file that contain all signatures and certificates. If I understand well, two users cannot sign the "same" file. Instead, the second user signs the document that was signed by the previous one. The digest was not the same :(

Comment: *"what I meant here is Signature field also has /M field with time, thus, it might not be possible to have same time and thus same hash to match with the hash we got at the time of calculating signature!"* - The **M** entry is optional, the signing time alternatively may be derived from a signing-time attribute in the CMS signature container or a digital time stamp in the CMS signature container. Or the entry can be set to the same time in both runs. As mentioned elsewhere, eSignature DSS uses PDFBox for signing in such a two-pass manner.

Comment: @scand1sk *"Well, additional issue is that several users can sign the original document, and I want to generate in fine a file that contain all signatures and certificates. If I understand well, two users cannot sign the "same" file. Instead, the second user signs the document that was signed by the previous one. The digest was not the same :( "* - indeed, this architecture is not appropriate for PDF signing. Interoperable PDF signing does not allow real parallel signatures, merely serial ones.

Answer (score 2):

The work flow after the edit, i.e. with

> 2. Other users signs the SHA256 digest using RSA. The signatures are added to the database.

instead of

> 2. The user signs the SHA256 digest using RSA. The signature is added to the database.

cannot be used for interoperable PDF signatures because they

- only allow for a single `SignerInfo` per embedded CMS signature container and
- require the signature to sign the complete current document revision except merely the placeholder for the signature container:

[image]

*(For some more backgrounds and references read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096).)*

Thus, the signatures of multiple users sign different hashes and (probably even worse for your architecture) the respective hash depends on the signature values of all previous signatures. Furthermore, if you want signatures with signature visualizations containing information on the signer in the PDF, these visualizations should be part of the signed content itself; adding them afterwards results in messages about changed field properties which is something people generally are not happy to see for signature fields.

---

If you are looking beyond interoperable PDF signatures, though, there are some options. E.g. PDF/CAdES-A (a proprietary format allowing arbitrary CAdES-A signatures in PDF signature fields) ignores the "single `SignerInfo` per embedded CMS signature container" restriction and so can allow for actual parallel signatures.

Of course such signatures, not being interoperable, usually will not be displayed and validated as desired by generic viewers and validators. E.g. Adobe Reader will only show information on one of the signers of PDF/CAdES-A parallel signatures.